# AsyncTask Pass an array to onProgressUpdate()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I got through some guides, and I know, how to pass many parameters into onProgressUpdate like this

```
@Override
protected void doInBackground(Void... params){
publishProgress("a","b");
}

@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... params){

String passed1 = params[0];
String passed1 = params[1];


}
```

And now. Is it somehow possible to send an array?

Like this

```
@Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params){
     String[] values = new String[2];
     values[0]="c";
     values[1]="d";
    publishProgress("a","b",values);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... params){

    String passed1 = params[0];
    String passed1 = params[1];
    String passed3 = params[3][0];
    String passed3 = params[3][1];


    }
```

Because exactly this is not working.
Any solutions? Please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code:

```
publishProgress("a","b",values);
```

Expects a signature of

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String, String, String[])
```

To pass an array, you need all the values together:

```
String[] values = new String[4];
values[0]="a";
values[1]="b";
values[2]="c";
values[3]="d";
publishProgress(values);
```

Comment: Well, honestly, not usable by my silution, I have to do it by another way in my solution. Anyway, thank you, maybe will be useful as archived topic for another people. Have a nice time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
int var1,var2,var3;
publishProgress(var1,var2,var3,.....);
```

and in onProgressUpdate:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){
int a = values[0];
int b = values[1];
int c = values[.....].......
```

Can be used with any Datatype, you need to mention in second parameter which is for onProgressUpdate

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,**Integer**,String>
```